# Oracle: subtract millisecond from a datetime

Tags: sql, oracle, function, date

I thought it was really simple but it isn't.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') 
          - 1/(24*50*60*1000) data 
FROM dual;
```

It simply doesn't work.

---

Other details:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') -
           NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*50*60*1000),'HOUR') data 
FROM dual;
```

doesn't work..

The right seems to be

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') -
           NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*25*60*1000),'HOUR') data 
FROM dual;
```

Why? How does it work?

Comment: I did not get your point. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Thinhbk:He wanted millisecond to be subtracted from that timestamp,if you look to the query above ,this will output you only `10/AUG/12`,and actually he wanted `09/AUG/12 11:59:59.999950000 PM ` as output .`Gik25` correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: Subtract one millisecond from the date

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For adding or subtracting an amount of time expressed as a literal you can use INTERVAL.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY')
     - INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND 
FROM dual;
```

As well there are now standard ways to express date and time literals and avoid the use of various database specific conversion functions.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-10-08 00:00:00' 
   - INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND DATA
FROM dual;
```

For your original question the time part of a day is stored in fractional days. So one second is:

```
1 / (hours in day * minutes in hour * seconds in a minute)
```

Divide by 1000 to get milliseconds.

```
1 / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Comment: +1 Interval literals are definitely the way to go.  Format models and date multiplication are just bugs waiting to happen.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*50*60*1000),'HOUR') data 
FROM dual;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
DATA                             
---------------------------------
09/AUG/12 11:59:59.999950000 PM  

1 row selected.
```

Comment: How do you simulate the OUTPUT?

Comment: It didn't work..
Correct seems to be:
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') -
           NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*25*60*1000),'HOUR') data 
FROM dual;
Why? I don't understand..

Comment: Not working. `SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') -
           NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*50*60*1000),'HOUR') data 
FROM dual;` gives the error: *FROM keyword not found where expected*

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka:It works for me ,try to align the text in one line ,its strange but this is how it is working :)

Answer (score 9):

The answer posted above subtracts a *tenth* of a millisecond from the date. I think what you want is the following:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY')-NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/1000,'SECOND')
  FROM dual;
```

**Output:**

```
DATA
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
09-AUG-12 11.59.59.999000000 PM
                   ^^^
                   |||
              tenths|thousandths
                    |
                hundredths
```

The following `NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*25*60*1000),'HOUR')` seems to work only because 24*25 = 600. But that number is wrong because 1/(600*60*1000) of an hour is a tenth of a millisecond, not a millisecond. If you want to use 'HOUR' in `NUMTODSINTERVAL()` you should use `1/(60*60*1000)` (sixty minutes in an hour, sixty seconds in a minute, 1000 ms in a second).

Answer (score 7):

This is correct (with a millisecond being 1000th of a second):-

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/1000,'SECOND') data FROM dual;


DATA
-----------------------------
09-AUG-12 23.59.59.999000000
```

As to why the other code isn't working it's because you aren't calculating a millisecond correctly.  An hour must be divided by 60 to give minutes and again by 60 to given seconds then by 1000 to give a millisecond, thus if you must use HOUR as the interval then it is:-

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(60*60*1000),'HOUR') as data FROM dual;

DATA
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
09-AUG-12 23.59.59.999000000
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('10.05.2012', 'DD.MM.YYYY') - 
       NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/1000, 'SECOND'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')  Res 
  from dual;

RES
-----------------------------
09.05.2012 23:59:59.999
```